# How to configure cache in a kubernetes gitlab instance?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I've setup gitlab (via helm chart 5.2.3 / gitlab ce 14.2.3) in my kubernetes cluster (1.21) on a bare-metal ubuntu machine.
As docker >= 19 has [enabled TLS as default](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/07/31/docker-in-docker-with-docker-19-dot-03/) I have to add some [configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#docker-in-docker-with-tls-enabled-in-kubernetes) to get `dind` in my CI working (to get access to docker).

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
variables:
DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2376
DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
DOCKER_CERT_PATH: "$DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR/client"
```

**values.yaml**

```
gitlab-runner:
runners:
    privileged: true
    config: |
    [[runners]]
        [runners.kubernetes]
        image = "ubuntu:20.04"
        privileged = true
        [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.empty_dir]]
        name = "docker-certs"
        mount_path = "/certs/client"
        medium = "Memory"
```

But with this I can't use `cache` anymore:

```
install dependencies:
stage: dependencies
script:
    - npm ci
cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    policy: push
    paths:
    - node_modules/
```

results in:

```
Creating cache main...
node_modules/: found 49948 matching files and directories 
No URL provided, cache will be not uploaded to shared cache server. Cache will be stored only locally. 
Created cache
```

The logs give me:

```
ERROR: Could not create cache adapter               error=cache factory not found: factory for cache adapter "" was not registered
```

So I tried to configure the cache:

```
gitlab-runner:
runners:
    privileged: true
    config: |
    [[runners]]
        [runners.kubernetes]
        image = "ubuntu:20.04"
        privileged = true
        [runners.cache]
            Type = "s3"
            Path = ""
            Shared = false
            [runners.cache.s3]
            ServerAddress = "minio.domain.com"
            BucketName = "gitlab-runner"
            BucketLocation = "none"
            Insecure = false
        [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.empty_dir]]
        name = "docker-certs"
        mount_path = "/certs/client"
        medium = "Memory"
```

which is nearly working, but the path is wrong:

```
Creating cache main...
node_modules/: found 49948 matching files and directories 
Uploading cache.zip to https://minio.domain.com/gitlab-runner/runner/yC3_5Zz4/project/4/main 
FATAL: received: 400 Bad Request                   
Failed to create cache
```

Before configuring the TLS (an with that there is no docker access) the working output was:

```
Creating cache main...
node_modules/: found 49948 matching files and directories 
Uploading cache.zip to https://minio.domain.com/runner-cache/gitlab-runner/project/4/main 
Created cache
```

So how do I have to setup the cache correctly?